# Software para criar Diagrama de Classes

Tags: java, classes, diagrama

Gostaria de saber quais softwares usados ou se existe algum site online para criar diagramas de classes, alguém poderia me indicar?

Comment: Perguntas assim são complicadas porque qualquer coisa serve como resposta, Em geral elas atarem várias pessoas dizendo o que gostam de usar, ou seja é tudo resposta baseada em opinião e só *link*, não ajuda nada. Também pode ser fora de escopo se considerar que só vai fornecer uma coleção de 8links*. Quando a pergunta é bem feita, até dá responder com algo significativo. Na forma atual, não produz respostas de verdade. Veja http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101. também tem outra que mostra como esse tipo de pergunta incentiva apenas opinião: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existem vários, **para download**:

- [StartUML](http://staruml.io/download)
- [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/)
- [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/index.html.en)
- Umbrello - `apt-get install umbrello`
- [Astah](http://jude.change-vision.com/jude-web/index.html)
- [Jude](http://jude.change-vision.com/jude-web/product/jude_pl.html)

Eu gosto do ArgoUML e do Dia, são bem simples de usar.

**Versões online**:

- [Genmymodel](https://www.genmymodel.com/)
- [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)

Eu não uso versões online, então não posso afirmar qual é melhor, mas Genmymodel é muito bem recomendado.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar o [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) , tem vários modelos de diagramas. 
Tem o [Astah](http://astah.net/editions/community) versão free também.
Recomendo usar o draw.io.

Answer (score 8):

Eu costumo usar o [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/download/index.html.en), gratuito e leve

Answer (score 6):

Existem muitos, dentre eles se destaca:

- [Astah](http://astah.net/) --> *Prefiro ele*
- [AgroUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/)

Existe até uma ferramenta que te permite criar diagramas a partir de código Java chamado:

- [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) --> *Faz tempo que não utilizo mas é uma ótima ferramenta.*